# First Item in Dropdown list loses attribute

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net

I have dropdownlist that is dynamically created and contains a list of users.  If the user meets a certain I apply a style attribute to highlight the user.  My ListItems will all highlight correctly, except the first one on the List. This seems odd that the first will act this way and be different than the others.

```
    ddlSupervisorList.Items(ddlSupervisorList.Items.Count - 1).Attributes.CssStyle.Value = "background:#cc66ff;"
```

If I select another user, the newly selected user will still maintain their highlight, but the first user will still not highlight.

I have even tried doing the following:

```
If ddlSupervisorList.SelectedItem.Equals(ddlSupervisorList.Items(ddlSupervisorList.Items.Count - 1)) Then
   ddlSupervisorList.SelectedItem.Attributes.CssStyle.Value = "background:#cc66ff;"
End If
```

but it will still not highlight the first item(default item) on load.

Comment: Why does your selection criteria = "ddlSupervisorList.Items.Count - 1".  Is that just for demonstration purposes or are you actually trying to select the last item in the list?

Comment: Honestly the if statement was just trying to force that if the item last item updated was the selected item, then I would force the 'SelectedItem' to have its attribute be appended with the CSSStyle.

Comment: Have you tried using firebug or ie dev tools to see what style attributes are actually applied to the item?  Perhaps something else is overriding your applied style.

Comment: It looks to be the Microsoft Defaults that are over riding it.  It does show that the style is applied to the Item.  Adding !important is not overriding it.

Comment: Let us see the HTML of whatever is being rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I went with using Some JQuery and javascript to fix the issue.  I picked up the drop down list ID and got the selected option.  If it was supposed to be highlighted  'availableSelected' was the cssclass, then I added it to the drop down list's css for the list row.

```
var userClientId = '#<%= ddlSupervisorList.ClientID %>';
var selectedId = userClientId + ' option:selected';
function clientIdChanged() 
{
    if ($(selectedId).hasClass('availableSelected')) {
        $(userClientId).addClass('availableSelected');
    }
    else {
        $(userClientId).removeClass('availableSelected');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    clientIdChanged();
    $(userClientId).bind('change', clientIdChanged);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

if it is being generated dynamically make sure you are not putting it in the if(!page.IsPostBack). on page_load you must re-render the drop down with the styles you want.

Comment: I have already checked and it does not have anything to do with isPostBack, because it is maintaining the styles on all of the other list items, just not  the first.